# SMB Server on Ubuntu is transferring to and from my Mac really slowly

Tags: finder, network, smb, nas

I have an iMac from mid-2011 with Ubuntu 23.04 on it, with an SMB server set up on it. When I connect to this server via my MacBook Pro (running macOS Monterey) in Finder, it's extremely slow to copy files to and from the share, and to rename files too. Both the iMac and MacBook are on the same network. The speed is about 500 KBs to 800 KBs per second.

I have searched a few questions that look similar to this, however they didn't seem to have helped.

Here is my config (smb.conf):

```
[global]
   read raw = Yes
   write raw = Yes
   socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_SNDBUF=64000 SO_RCVBUF=64000 SO_KEEPALIVE
   min receivefile size = 16384
   use sendfile = true
   aio read size = 16384
   aio write size = 16384

   workgroup = NASThing

   server string = Super Cool Server

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

   max log size = 1000

   logging = file

   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes

   map to guest = bad user

   usershare allow guests = no

#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[NAS]
comment = My Wannabe NAS
path = /home/[omitted]/[omitted]/NAS
valid users = [omitted]
read only = no
guest ok = no
```

I don't know if this is a problem with my server, or with macOS.
So, how can I improve the speed/fix the slow speeds?

Comment: Wired or wireless?  If wireless, is it 802.11g or n?  What does the signal quality look like?  Can you try this wired?

Comment: I'm using Ethernet, so Wired.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, adding these lines...

```
vfs objects = recycle acl_xattr catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:aapl = yes
fruit:encoding = native
fruit:locking = none
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:resource = file
```

...fixes it. I don't know why, but it does.
([source of these lines](https://serverfault.com/questions/999920/very-slow-smb-speeds-on-macos))

Previously I tried it with just...

```
vfs objects = fruit
fruit:aapl = yes
fruit:encoding = native
fruit:locking = none
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:resource = file
```

...but it made files not show up. Folders showed though, just no files.